# How do I get this loop to write to CSV after each row iteration rather than after each file?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have the following method:

```
  csvs = Dir["#{@dir_name}/#{@state}/*.csv"]

  csvs.each do |csv|
    city = csv.split(/[\/]|.csv-updated|.csv/).last
    new_csv = "#{@dir_name}/#{@state}/emails/#{city}-with-emails.csv"
    CSV.open(new_csv, "a+", write_headers: true, headers: ["Company_Name","Website","Street_Address", "City", "State", "Zip", "Phone","Email1", "Email2", "Email3", "Email4", "Email5"]) do |new_csv_row|
      CSV.foreach(csv, headers: true) do |row|
          website = row['Website']
          begin
            page = YPCrawler::PageParser.new website
            links = page.compile_all_links(website)
            emails = page.compile_all_emails(links)
            new_csv_row << (row << emails.join(","))
          rescue
            next
          end
      end
    end
  end
```

What happens though is that it doesn't write to the new CSV on each row processed, it only does it once it has processed an entire CSV file has been processed, as opposed to each row within that old CSV file. I assume it processes that old CSV file and stores the results in memory, and then when that CSV file is done it just dumps the entire thing from memory into the file. I don't particularly like this because CSV files have different lengths and I don't want to ever run out of memory since I am processing so many files.

I initially had the `CSV.open(new_csv)` and `CSV.foreach(csv)`, but the issue I had is that after every row it kept writing a header row, which is not what I wanted.

I just want the header row written once, at the top of the file, and then the row added appropriately.

What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: So you want all the csv data written in a single file with headers?

Comment: @Nikhil Yes. The data comes from two places. One part comes from the old CSV via `row` and the other comes from through those methods that create `emails`.

Comment: Does each old csv has header?

Comment: @Nikhil Yes, they all do.

Comment: and headers are these: `["Company_Name","Website","Street_Address", "City", "State", "Zip", "Phone","Email1", "Email2", "Email3", "Email4", "Email5"]` right?

Comment: @Nikhil Yep....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can write the header explicitly. This is based on my understanding so far with our comments

```
headers = ["Company_Name","Website","Street_Address", "City", "State", "Zip", "Phone","Email1", "Email2", "Email3", "Email4", "Email5"]
set_headers = true

csvs.each do |csv|
  city = csv.split(/[\/]|.csv-updated|.csv/).last
  new_csv = "#{@dir_name}/#{@state}/emails/#{city}-with-emails.csv"
  CSV.open(new_csv, "a+") do |new_csv_row|
    new_csv_row << headers if set_headers
    set_headers = false
    CSV.foreach(csv, headers: true) do |row|
      website = row['Website']
      begin
        page = YPCrawler::PageParser.new website
        links = page.compile_all_links(website)
        emails = page.compile_all_emails(links)
        new_csv_row << (row << emails.join(","))
      rescue
        next
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @marcamillion: Does this help?

Comment: The issue isn't so much about the headers. The issue is with the creation of the new CSV. Basically, what I want to happen is, after each `new_csv_row` is appended to, I want the `new_csv` file updated.

Comment: then `CSV.open(new_csv, "a+")` can be moved inside `CSV.foreach(csv, headers: true) do |row|` loop? BTW where are you using that `new_csv` upated filr

Comment: Ahh moving the `CSV.open` did work. What do you mean where am I using it? I am using it right in that `CSV.open` call. Also, another issue I am having is with the last line. the `new_csv_row << (row << emails.join(","))`. What that does is it takes the contents of `emails` and converts it into one long ass comma-separated string and sticks it into one cell. What I want to do is to put each element from `emails` into a different column but within that same row, i.e. `Email2, Email3, Email4, etc.`. Now, I am getting 5 - 10 emails all in Email2. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Happy to help. For the email column values. you need to add `emails.each{|e| row << e}` after `emails = ...` line and then do `new_csv_row << row`

Comment: Ahh interesting. That does make sense.

Comment: Both of your suggestions work like a charm. Thanks for the help!